Change description of transaction in Stripe Connect
I'm trying to implement Stripe Connect in our app and I'm struggling with customizing the transaction description. Currently, users see only something like py_1PfcRZRwYeD3qF8fSkArkTKu, which I believe is the destination_payment.
I'm using stripe sdk like this:
    const organizerStripeAccountId = await getOrganizerStripeAccountId(eventId)

      if (!organizerStripeAccountId) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          error: 'Organizer account not found',
        })
      }

      const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: amount * 100,
        currency: currency,
        transfer_data: {
          destination: organizerStripeAccountId,
        },
        description: `Payment from ${user.email || user.name}`,
        metadata: {
          userId: user._id.toString(),
          eventId: eventId,
          userEmail: user.email,
          userName: user.name,
        },
      })

      const payment = new Payment({
        eventId: eventId,
        userId: user._id,
        amount: amount,
        currency: currency,
        paymentIntentId: paymentIntent.id,
        status: 'pending',
        metadata: paymentIntent.metadata,
      })

      await payment.save()

However, this only modifies the description and metadata in the payment intent and does not affect what the user sees in their dashboard.
Do you have any idea how I can manage this problem? Any help would be highly appreciated.

This question is similar to: Stripe propagate paymentIntent description to Connected Account's transfer payment. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

see also : https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-can-you-carry-over-the-description-or-metadata-to-the-payment-on-the-connected-account-for-a-destination-charge
